# Regex matching "four characters, followed by an unknown No of digits."

Tags: java, regex

An example of how the Strings may look:

```
TADE000177
TADE007,daFG
TADE0277 DFDFG
```

Comment: Your examples do not match the description given in your title. You ask for "four characters, follow by an unknown No of digits", but only your first example follows that pattern.

The second example is four characters, some digits, a comma, some characters.

Which are you after?

Edit: Might have jumped the gun here - are those strings examples of input from which you wish to parse the pattern (as opposed to examples of the pattern itself)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly four characters followed by 1 or more digits: `[A-Z]{4}\d+`

Remember to escape the backslash if you put it in a string literal.

Breakdown:

- `[A-Z]…`: An upper case letter, equivalent to `\p{Upper}`

  - To also include lower case letters, you could instead use `[A-Za-z]` or `\p{Alpha}`
- `…{4}…` exactly 4 times
- `…\d…+` a digit
- `…+` 1 or more times

  - To allow 0 digits, you could change to `*`.

Answer (score 6):

It's a little unclear what you want.

If you mean four capital letters from A to Z, followed by at least one digit in 0-9 you could try this:

```
"^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]+"
```

- If instead of capital letters you want to allow any character except newline change `[A-Z]` to `.`.
- If you want to also allow zero digits change the `+` to a `*`.

Answer (score -1):

If i understood correctly what you're asking for you can try: `.{4}\d*`

Answer (score -1):

```
^\w{4}.*$
```

Matches a string starting with 4 characters followed by any number of any other charcters.
Your examples include spaces and punctuation, if you know exactly which characters are allowed then you might want to use this pattern.

```
^\w{4}[A-z\d<other known characters go here>]*$
```

Remember to remove the < and > too :)